# How to set an EditText to 0 if it is left blank

Tags: android

Basically I have four EditText fields lets call them apple, pear, banana and orange. The user enters how many of each were bought then when you press a button it calculates the total fruit.

```
public class Fruit extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Enter amount of fruit bought");
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText o = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        TextView sum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        float apple = Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
        float pear = Float.parseFloat(p.getText().toString());
        float banana = Float.parseFloat(b.getText().toString());
        float orange = Float.parseFloat(o.getText().toString());
        float total;


        total=apple+pear+banana+orange;

        sum.setText(Float.toString(total));

    }}
```

How do I go about making sure if the user leaves a field blank the program treats it as 0 and still gives the total fruit bought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String ensureFruit(String str){

     return TextUtils.isEmpty(str)? "0": str;

}
```

and use it as

```
float apple = Float.parseFloat(ensureFruit(a.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I tried checking if the length is >0 or checking is it is a NaN but nether worked so thank you.